# Solving Two Conditional Function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a school problem from a marketing class. I couldn't have an idea. Please take a look and any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

**Calculate the sales that came from NJ and customers # that contains a number 8.**

I thought about using SUMIFS, but no idea for calculating cells that contain number 8

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: Do you need a single formula?

Comment: I came up with a pretty ugly formula. Definitely to know more ideas! So what's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1:**

You can use the `FIND` function to check whether a number contains a specific digit.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(FIND(8,A2:A9))*(B2:B9="NJ")*C2:C9)
```

**Option 2:**

A slightly more appropriate way of using `SUMPRODUCT` and ditching boolean arithmetic would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(ISNUMBER(FIND(8,A2:A9))),N(B2:B9="NJ"),C2:C9)
```

- The `N` function is required to change boolean values to either 0 or 1 (False and True, respectively).
- The `ISNUMBER` checks the result of `FIND`: a number means the value was found, an error means it wasn't (which becomes false when passed to `ISNUMBER`).

**Option 3:**

An alternative involves using array formula with `SUM` instead of `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUM(ISNUMBER(FIND(8,A2:A9))*(B2:B9="NJ")*C2:C9)
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

**Note:** I've assumed your data is within the range `A2:C9`.

Comment: M, I loved the option 3. It's easier for me to understand and use it in a different way. Thank you so much. I didn't think about the SUMPRODUCT Function